# Cloud Endpoints rejecting float value from javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, floating-point, google-cloud-endpoints

Calling my endpoints API method 
*locate(@Named("latitude") float latitude, @Named("longitude") float longitude)*

from the following javascript client code, where pos is type 'google.maps.LatLng'
*locate({'latitude':pos.lat(),'longitude':pos.lng()*

returns status 400, saying
*code: 400, message: "Invalid float value: '77.08659999999998'."*

I am using GAE 1.8.3. lat() and lng() return a (JS 64-bit floating point) number, which API should be able to convert to java 32-bit float.

This seems to work fine in my dev server, but not on GAE. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Invalid float value: '77.08659999999998'." is gone by using double instead of float type method parameters in ApiMethod.

*locate(@Named("latitude") double latitude, @Named("longitude") double longitude)*